# Need to remove lines from txt file using Windows XP/7 Batch file

Tags: windows, search, batch-file

I have a script that searches log files and finds a string of characters: i.e "[501005]" without quotes. In some lines, this string is followed immediately by a variable word, i.e "[501005]RF".  On some lines, the string is followed by two space, then a variable number, i.e "[501005]  02". I need only the lines that DO NOT have the spaces.  I cannot search for only my string follwed by another specfic string, as there are too many possibilities.  I get errors using

```
findstr /i /v "]  " /c:"[501005" *inputfile* > *outputfile*
```

If I remove the /v "]  " parameter, i get all the lines that have my string, so i know the search works.  My only hang up is eliminating the unwanted lines. Here is a sample (and as you can see, the number of lines also is variable):

```
2013/10/30 00:04:26  [501005]INT_L3_ATCS  010.1.11 (28b)  TX  29 bytes
2013/10/30 00:04:26  [501005]  02 8B 25 00 60 00 AE 73 4A 5A 1A A5 A2 A2 23 4A 
2013/10/30 00:04:26  [501005]  A3 55 A1 00 34 02 02 12 48 03 00 00 08 
2013/10/30 00:04:26  [501005]CODELINE_INDICATION_MSG 010.150.006.046 010.1.11 (28b)  RX  33 bytes
2013/10/30 00:04:26  [501005]  02 8B 64 00 8A 5E EA 23 4A A3 55 A1 73 4A 5A 1A 
2013/10/30 00:04:26  [501005]  A5 A2 A2 00 92 02 02 12 8B 03 00 03 08 00 00 01 
2013/10/30 00:04:26  [501005]  3D 
2013/10/30 00:04:26  [501005]RF_L3_ACK 010.1.11 (28b)  TX  12 bytes
2013/10/30 00:04:26  [501005]  02 8B 34 8C 0E 73 4A 5A 1A A5 A2 A2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
findstr "[501005]" input.txt | findstr /V /C:"]  " > output.txt
```

Comment: Genius!  Thanks so much! +1! (i don't have enough rep to actually upvote.. :( )

Comment: so, findstr /r /i "*backslash*[501005][^ ]"?  this gave me all the lines, even that did not have [501005].

Comment: This doesn't work as expected. `findstr "[501005]"` is the same as `findstr "[015]"` (Regex). You should better use `findstr "\[501005]"`.

Answer (score 0):

This should remove the lines with the spaces:

```
findstr /l /v /c:"] " inputfile > outputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

remove lines with `[501005]` followed by two spaces:

```
findstr /vc:"\[501005]  " input.txt>output.txt
```